# Extjs form.submit() call changing field value

Tags: forms, extjs, submit

I can see what are the values of the fields just before the submit:

```
var itemsForm = '';
function mostraItems(item, index, length) { itemsForm += item.id + ':' + item.name + ':' + item.value + ':' + index + '\n'; }
myForm.form.items.each(mostraItems);
alert (itemsForm);
myForm.form.submit({...
```

The problem I have is that the submitted values are different from what I can see before the form.submit() call. One of the fields is a ComboBox:

```
var myCombo = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
    //autoWidth: true,
    width: 250,
    displayField: 'theFieldText',
    editable: false,
    emptyText: 'Select something ...',
    fieldLabel: 'Some text',
    listeners: { 'select': { fn: theOnSelect, scope: this} },
    mode: 'local',
    selectOnFocus: true,
    store: theStore,
    triggerAction: 'all',
    typeAhead: true,
    valueField: 'theFieldValue',
    name: 'fieldName'
});
```

What is going in the request is the sum of the valueField and the displayField. Say the value field contains "1" and the displayField contains "some text" then what goes in the request is "1 (some text)" in instead of just the value "1".

There is something happening after or during the form.submit() call and I can't find what it is.

Using Ext 2.3

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything unusual happening during form submit call.

First of all, check the form values just before the form is submitted (but not the way you do it now). Do you use Firebug (I hope yes)?

```
myForm.getValues();
```

gives you key/value pairs as they will be submitted.

So type into console

```
Ext.getCmp('your-form-id').getForm().getValues();
```

or put into your code

```
console.log(myForm.getValues());
```

instead of alert() and see an output. Then, when you submit the form in a standard way

```
myForm.submit({url: 'submit-url'})
```

there is no chance your values will be different. How do you submit the form?

Answer (score 0):

As Igor described, you should always use `form.getForm().getValues()` to see what Values are being submitted.

And if for any particular field you are not happy with the way your data is being formatted or displayed or calculated, you can always override the `getSubmitData` method for that field.